# Designer ignores BasedOn Style during design time, works during runtime

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, expression-blend

There seems to be a bug or limitation on the WPF designer's ability to infer the style to display during design time.

I am skinning my app and have a base window style in my app.xaml:

```
 <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="WindowStyleBase" TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}" BasedOn="{StaticResource WindowStyleBase}">
            <!--  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" /> -->
        </Style>

    </Application.Resources>
```

And I skin my window using the static resource `WindowStyle` :

```
<Window x:Class="XamlBasedOnBreaker.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Style="{StaticResource WindowStyle}">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now when I run the application, I see the red background, but during design time in visual studio 2013 and expression blend the background is white (default). The designer does not apply the proper style.

How do I fix this? I have multiple user controls etc on which I want the `WindowStyle` that's why I subclass the style and use `BasedOn`. If I move the red color into `WindowStyle` instead of `WindowStyleBase` it works, but this would result in too much copy paste code, even if I would use resources for the brushes as I have quite a number of user controls.

Further more I am skinning a dark theme and having a white background during design time is more than inconvenient.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this issue; I'm struggling with the same problem

Comment: @SumGuy yes, I switched to T4 and preprocess the styles. I create offline "generated" styles not having based on. This is some sort of compile time inheritance pattern.